# How fast does $\,\big(1+\frac 1n\big)^n$ converges to e?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, rate-of-convergence

How fast does the sequence $(1+1/n)^n$ converge to $\mathrm{e}$?

Is the difference more like $\frac1n$ or more like $\mathrm{e}^{-n}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe that
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=\mathrm{e}^{n\log(1+\frac{1}{n})}
=\mathrm{e}^{n(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+\mathcal O(n^{-3}))}
=\mathrm{e}\cdot\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{2n}+\mathcal O(n^{-2}))}=\mathrm{e}\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}+\mathcal O(n^{-2})\right)
$$
Hence
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n-\mathrm{e}=-\frac{\mathrm{e}}{2n}+\mathcal O(n^{-2})
$$

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but that seems to be more useful for the quotient than the difference.

Comment: @Tara See my modified answer.

Comment: Oh right, thanks for your edit.

Comment: Should be $1/n\log\cdots$ not $n\log\cdots$ ?